# show only one id from json php

Tags: php, jsonp

my question is: how i can show only id 2 from this code ? (the code show all id)

this is a file.php json encode

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$server = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not  connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM flo";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

relative json result

```
([
{
"id":"1",
"Marca":"puma",
 },
 {
 "id":"2",
 "Marca":"fila",
 }
 ]);
```

thx a lot

Comment: `SELECT * FROM flo WHERE id  = 2`?

Comment: Also, its better to use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, only if u havent support legacy project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Jon Stirling solved it in comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752708/show-only-one-id-from-json-php#comment62974952_37752708

Comment: @JonStirling Now there's ^ a first, *eh?*  ;-) Least I think *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Noooooo :P. Though that's only one option :).

Comment: @JonStirling Given the amount of upvotes you received for it, I'd call this one solved in its own right ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: Wait, I haven't tested it on sqlfiddle!

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Why would you want to test it? It's pretty obvious here ;-) unless their server no longer supports the `mysql_` API, then that would be a different story.

Comment: I'll never make a joke again.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez It's okay, some of us picked up on it.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez *lol* - Ah, got it ;-) well then.... *ha ha ha!* is in order then ;-)

Comment: Lol soz 4 stupid question guys...i think i need a rest api...

Answer (score 0):

In order to display id=2 (or any other) from JSON, it's necessary to search the id, like this (will display "fila") :

```
<?php

$data = '[ { "id":"1",
             "Marca":"puma"
           },
           { "id":"2",
             "Marca":"fila"
           },
           { "id":"3",
             "Marca":"nike"
           }
         ]';
$json = json_decode( $data );

foreach ( $json as $record ) // VISIT EACH RECORD.
  if ( $record->id == "2" )
    echo $record->Marca . "<br/><br/>";

?>
```

Notice how each field in the data becomes a property in JSON ("id" becomes $record->id).

Comment: @user3451888, this answer is useful in case you have JSON alone and not SQL.